# Stop scrolling of the page but still take in a vertical scroll value?

Tags: javascript, css

On http://www.beargrylls.com/ its intro stops the normal scrolling on the page but uses the scroll event to do effects.

How do you:

1. Stop the scrolling effect on the page without an overflow:hidden css rule
2. How do you do #1 while still taking in scrolling offset values (I'm assuming this is what is being done).
   Thanks.

Comment: the "intro" is an image wrapped in a div - it simply scrolls until the end of the image.

Comment: Ahh I see thanks that helps!

Comment: What would make sense is that the scroll actually goes to another element inside of the page, as if you scroll the bar manually nothing changes. The scroll bar for the second element is then hidden, and nothing scrolls because `position: fixed`, and it interprets the scroll from there.